# how to use a variable as second parameter of an android intent?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have multiple activities that use same layout
for example activity1, activity2, activity3 and ...
there is a button in the layout.xml that I want use it to go to next activity.
if I,m in activity1 the button sends user to activity2, if he is in activity2 the button sends him to activity3 and ...
Here is my code to start new activity in android.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

how can i use a variable instead of secondActivity.class

something like this:

```
var goToActivity = secondActivity.class
Intent intent = new Intent(this, goToActivity);
startActivity(intent);
```

I want to load this variable from a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Class::forName` method:

```java
String className = "com.example.myapp.secondActivity";  // or get the full class name from DB
Class klass = Class.forName(className);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, klass);
```

Comment: this is my package name: com.example.myapp  and this is my activity: secondActivity. but the code says classNotFoundExcption

Comment: So, you should use `"com.example.myapp.secondActivity"`. Or, more generally `getPackageName() + "secondActivity"`